# Insertion algorithm for binary search tree not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function that inserts a node into a binary search tree. I have seen several examples and it seems to me that my algorithm should be working, but it is failing the test for some reason.

```html
def insert(tr, el):
    """ function to insert an element into a binary search tree
    following the rules of binary search trees.
    
    return: an updated tree
    precondition: assumed all elements unique
    """

    if tr == None: 
        return createEyecuBST(el, None)
    elif el < tr.value:
        if tr.left == None:
            tr.left = createEyecuBST(el, tr)
            return tr
        else: return insert(tr.left, el)
    elif el > tr.value:
        if tr.right == None:
            tr.right = createEyecuBST(el, tr)
            return tr
        else: return insert(tr.right, el)
    return None
```

Comment: Are you intending to have an empty function body, or is this a formatting error?

Comment: @Tritium21 I'm sorry, I dont understand what you mean. Are you saying you can't see what is inside the insert function?

Comment: I am saying, the code as posted has nothing in the function body.  its not indented.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean that's a formatting error. All the code there should be inside the insert function. I'

Comment: Should be formatted properly now.

Comment: Some nitpicks.  Don't check if a value is None with ==, use the is operator.  also, don't end your function with return None, python does that for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two lines which appear problematic in your code:

```
else: return insert(tr.left, el)
```

and

```
else: return insert(tr.right, el)
```

In those cases your function will return a subtree (either the left or the right one) of `tr` whereas you want your function to return the updated `tr` tree. I think you should replace these lines by:

```
else:
    insert(tr.left, el)
    return tr
```

And similarly for `tr.right`.